# Realm android executeTransactionAsync not calling onSuccess

Tags: android, realm

**I am trying to add 50 records of student(realm object) generating  random data. onSuccess is never being called. I need to perform some task on successful insert....**

```
   public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private static final String ALPHA_NUMERIC_STRING = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";

RealmList<Student> mStudentList;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ((Button) findViewById(R.id.simple_insert)).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,SimpleInsertActivity.class));
        }
    });

    ((Button) findViewById(R.id.buld_insert)).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mStudentList = new RealmList<>();
            final Realm mRealm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();


            mRealm.executeTransactionAsync(new Realm.Transaction() {
                @Override
                public void execute(Realm realm) {
                    for(int i=0;i<50;i++){
                        String s =randomAlphaNumeric(8);
                        Log.i(getClass().getSimpleName(),"------------------------name : " + s);

                        Student student = realm.createObject(Student.class);//new Student();
                        student.setName(randomAlphaNumeric(8));
                        mStudentList.add(student);
                    }
                    Log.i(getClass().getSimpleName(),"----------------------------inserting data");
                    realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(mStudentList);
                }
            }, new Realm.Transaction.OnSuccess() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess() {

                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "inserted successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Log.i(getClass().getSimpleName(),"----------------------------after success :: " +
                    mRealm.where(Student.class).findAll().size());
                }
            }, new Realm.Transaction.OnError() {
                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable error) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Log.e(MainActivity.this.getClass().getSimpleName(),"-----------------------error : " + error.toString());
                }
            });
            mRealm.close();


        }
    });

    ((Button) findViewById(R.id.delete)).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            AppClass.deleteRealmDatabase();
        }
    });
}

public static String randomAlphaNumeric(int count) {
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    while (count-- != 0) {
        int character = (int)(Math.random()*ALPHA_NUMERIC_STRING.length());
        builder.append(ALPHA_NUMERIC_STRING.charAt(character));
    }
    return builder.toString();
}
```

}

```
public class Student extends RealmObject {
public static final String KEY_ROLL_NO = "rollNo";
public static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
@PrimaryKey
String rollNo;
String name;

public Student(String s) {
    this.rollNo = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
    this.name = s;
}

public Student() {

}

public String getRollNo() {
    return rollNo;
}

public void setRollNo(String rollNo) {
    this.rollNo = rollNo;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
```

}

---

Log : 
...............
 [ 06-27 05:13:55.327 28186:28560 I/]------------------------name :NRW29XS7

[ 06-27 05:13:55.327 28186:28560 I/]------------------------name : 2MS9QSB0

[ 06-27 05:13:55.327 28186:28560 I/]------------------------name : BJ2JHHHV

[ 06-27 05:13:55.327 28186:28560 I/]----------------------------inserting data

Comment: can we see the log of the execution?

Comment: @LucaNicoletti I have updated question. It contains last few records of loop and log inside execute. I am not getting anything else in my log

Comment: Does mStudentList extends RealmObject?

Comment: yes @LucaNicoletti. its class Student extends RealmObject {}

Comment: Students it's not StudentList. If mStudentList is a List<Object> that might cause problems: realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(mStudentList); because copyToRealmOrUpdate need a RealmObject

Comment: @LucaNicoletti I have updated question. I have pasted my whole code

Comment: move realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate inside the for loop.
realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(student). As I thought, it's not a RealmObject, i think that's the problem.

Comment: Didn't worked. @LucaNicoletti

Comment: @LucaNicoletti can you refer me any link which is having such type of working example?

Comment: I don't know any links with a working example. I just suggest to do as follow: create objects(Students) and the List<Student> outside the transaction. Inside the transaction just add them with a copyToRealOrUpdate(Student)

Comment: @LucaNicoletti I have tried initially but it was not working so I did this implementation.

Comment: Does the debugger get to the last line of execute? And in the first on onSuccess?

Comment: going till last line of execute but not coming on first on onSuccess

Comment: @LucaNicoletti I had been closing instance out of the Async

Comment: Oh! So the realm was closed, and the onSucces faded away. Didn't noticed that! Sorry! Glad you find out the solution!

Comment: @LucaNicoletti please help me with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38142985/when-trying-to-executetransactionasync-it-returns-error-in-realm

Answer (score 2):

I have been closing Realm instance in main thread so it was not getting instance and onSuccess was not getting called